# Resource owner password credential flow and "remebmer me" functionality (ie cookies)

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am using `IdentityServer3` to provide authentication and authorization for a new `ng2` web application. My server side is pretty much the example provided at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity/WebHost.

On the client side I've set up a login page that uses the `roclient` (resource owner client) flow with `password` `grant_type` to obtain a `jwt` after a successful call to `POST /core/connect/token`. Right now I save that to the `localStorage` and use it for future calls.

My questions are as follows:

1. How would I go about implementing "remember me" functionality? Would I use refresh tokens to vary the expiration of the token or would I try to use cookies somehow -
2. And is there a built-in way in `IdentityServer3` to get a cookie from a bearer token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Remember me" in the SPA? Using localStorage is about your only choice. Given your decision to use resource owner password flow, you are not benefiting from SSO. If you were dong redirects, then you could issue persistent cookies at IdentityServer to have a more standard "Remember me" implementation.
2. No.